# How to fit form view controller in View using eureka lib?

Tags: swift, tableview, eureka-forms

I have a custom pop up view, and I want to show `eureka` in this custom view

MultipleSelectorRow. But last rows of tableview doesn't show nor scrolls in this view.

I think `eureka` `formviewcontroller` doesn't fit the view's size.

how can i do this ? how can i show the last items of tableview's cell ?

any advice or sample code please ?

**here is my formviewcontroller**

```
 formController.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 8, y: currentY)
 formController.view.frame.size = CGSize(width: dialogViewWidth - 16 , height: dialogViewWidth-32)
```

should I create tableview programmatically with custom size and connect formviewcontroller's tableview with this tableview ?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. Then I did some changes in Eureka files named  `Core.swift`. So just go the file and `heightForFooterInSection` to `0`. Something like this -

```
open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
```

if this doesn't work try to set constraint programmatically do not use hardcoded numbers.